# Proper way to quit a function in Python

Tags: python, function, quit

Assume I have the following ;

```
def test():
    while 1:
        a = b
        time.sleep(60)
        c = b
        if(c==a):
            do something
            then quit the function
```

What is the proper way to quit from a function having this structure ?

Comment: downvotes *without* explanation don't help anyone .. agreed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use a `return` statement.

That would be the most direct way, by just placing the `return` where you want to quit ("then quit the function").

```
  if(c==a):
     do something
     return
```

You could also use this to return any results you have to the calling code.

Eg., `return some_results`

[Python doc for return](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `return` statement: eg

```
def test():
    while 1:
        a = b
        time.sleep(60)
        c = b
        if c == a:
            print a
            return
```

`break` would also work, by leaving the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `return` statement to exit the function call.

```
def blah():
    return  # Returns None if nothing passed back with it
def blah():
    return some_value, some_value2 # Return some values with it if you want.
```